# Chrome and Firefox viewport width 1519px and not 1920px

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox

Why is my viewport width in Chrome and Firefox 1519px, with no zoom on a 1920px screen?

I'm not using any plugins for Firefox.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is because it's checking your browser window and not your actual screen size.

Answer (score 0):

The reasons might be a few: 1) Your browser window is not maximized (full width) If you resize it, the viewport changes respectively 2) Your resolution is not set on the recommended one through the windows display settings

Answer (score 0):

The 1519px width is the default viewport setting (with vertical scrollbar) when using 1920px resolution in desktop browsers. As a user you can use the browser zoom.

If you're a front-end developer, you can change the zoom and get 1920px width:

```css
body { 
    zoom: 0.8;
}
```